# Use of Bootstrap and Flexbox in one Project

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox, react-bootstrap

I'm working on a front-end project based on React. I was just wondering if there's a possibility to combine usage of Bootstrap 3 and Flexbox in one project, since I would like to utilize both the convenience of using Bootstrap components (using react-bootstrap package) and the layout capabilities of Flexbox, which gets ruined when used together with bootstrap as I've tried before. Is there any way to make them work together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the flex css frameworks has a common class names like `row` , `col-*`, which conflicts with the bootstrap class names.

You can try this, http://bulma.io/

Of course, it offers more than a grid, but you can just give its a try.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex-row > [class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.flex-row.row:after, 
.flex-row.row:before {
  display: flex;
}
```

This works with React-Bootstrap:

```
<Row className="show-grid row-no-padding flex-row">
```

Comment: By the way, use React-Bootstrap: This is a best solution! 
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html

Answer (score 0):

Apparantly your prayer is already being answered...
[flexbox in Bootstrap](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/flexbox/)

Comment: Yeah I know they're working on it with bootstrap 4, but I guess, not with Bootstrap 3 yet. Right?